# How long before fruit tree grafts begin bearing fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, grafting, apples

If I graft a scion from one apple tree onto another mature tree, how long will it take for the graft to begin bearing fruit?

Comment: What kind of graft? I splice graft on the end of a fruiting branch will be able to bear in 2 years, but if you're doing rind grafting or something, it'll be a lot longer.

Comment: I'm attempting grafting for the first time, so if you can give an answer that covers the time to bear for common techniques that would be great -- my decision on how to go about it will depend somewhat on what will make it happen faster.

Comment: Are you thinking of changing over an entire tree, or a large section of one, or just doing something small?

Comment: How did it go then?

Answer (score 4):

Two years, it needs a growing season to establish, will set leaf buds the first winter and will start setting flower buds the second winter. Sometimes you'll get an early blossom, but you should cut it off early so it doesn't stress (physically or nutritionally) the graft.

Answer (score 4):

If you splice graft, whip and tongue graft, or bud (or any of the many similar grafts) onto stems that are under 1/2" in diameter, it should produce budwood in 2-3 years.

<sup>splice graft:</sup>

[image]

Generally with a diameter larger than that, at least with apple, you'll be rind grafting or cleft grafting. These will put out lots of growth in the next few years, to rebuild the removed mass, and often don't fruit for 5-7 years. Dwarf trees are always faster.

<sup>rind graft:</sup>

[image]

Comment: There sure are lots of different terms for grafting. I call the first one whip grafting, and the second one is like a hybrid of bud and cleft grafting. Pretty ingenious. What do you do if more than one graft takes? Do you thin them so they don't compete?

Comment: @Escoce no, all of them take when properly done. Proper training is then required to keep each branch controlled in it's own space.